# Remove a particular word in a list of lists if it appears after a set of words

Tags: python, regex, list, replace, nested-lists

I have a list of words
`list1=['duck','crow','hen','sparrow']`
and a list of sentences
`list2=[['The crow eats'],['Hen eats blue seeds'],['the duck is cute'],['she eats veggies']]`
I want to remove every occurance of the word 'eats' if it appears exactly after any of the words from the list.

desired output= `[['The crow','Hen blue seeds','the duck is cute'],['she eats veggies']]`

```
def remove_eats(test):
  for i in test:
    for j in i:
     for word in list1:
        j=j.replace(word + " eats", word)
        print(j)
        break
```

`remove_eats(list2)`

The replace method is not really working for the strings. Could you help me out? Is it possble with Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex such as the below, which has a series of alternating *positive look-behinds*. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t3qpbj/1))

```
(?:(?<=[Dd]uck)|(?<=[Cc]row)|(?<=[Hh]en)|(?<=[Ss]parrow))\s+eats?\b
```

Python example, using builtin `re` module:

```py
import re

list1 = ['duck', 'crow', 'hen', 'sparrow']

look_behinds = '|'.join(f'(?<=[{w[0].swapcase()}{w[0]}]{w[1:]})'
                        for w in list1)

EATS_RE = re.compile(rf'(?:{look_behinds})\s+eats?\b')

sentences = [['The crow eats'],
             ['Hen eats blue seeds'],
             ['the duck is cute'],
             ['she eats veggies']]

repl_sentences = [[EATS_RE.sub('', s, 1) for s in x] for x in sentences]
print(repl_sentences)
```

Out:

```py
[['The crow'], ['Hen blue seeds'], ['the duck is cute'], ['she eats veggies']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly fine. I was wondering if there are two stop words present in a sentence, like "Hen eats sushi and crow eats veggies" is it possble to remove the first occurance of eats only? Output=Hen sushi and crow eats veggies?

Comment: @Codingamethyst Yes, it should be relatively straightforward to achieve this. The [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function accepts a `count` parameter, so you could just pass it as 1 so it will return after the first replacement. I also updated my answer above to indicate how this would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a case insensitive pattern and generate an alternation with the words that you want to keep in a capture group.

Then match the word eats after it that you want to remove and replace with capture group 1.

An example with the assembled pattern:

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(duck|crow|hen|sparrow)\s+eats\b"
list2 = [['The crow eats'], ['Hen eats blue seeds'], ['the duck is cute'], ['she eats veggies']]

res = [[re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s, 0, re.I) for s in lst] for lst in list2]

print(res)
```

Output

```
[
  ['The crow'],
  ['Hen blue seeds'],
  ['the duck is cute'],
  ['she eats veggies']
]
```

See a [regex demo](https://ideone.com/sQvkGE) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sQvkGE)